# How to avoid ETIMEDOUT on google api node js client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using [Google Api Nodejs Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and I receive frequently some timeouts on my API calls (the biggest part of my requests are on the Gmail Api).
I can perform at the same time some Google Cloud SQL requests, so it does not seem to be a network problem on my server.
You can find below some of the timeouts that are in my logs.

```
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"216.58.219.234","port":443}
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"216.58.219.202","port":443}
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"209.85.201.95","port":443}
```

Is there any way to avoid these timeouts ?
It is possible to specify fields that will be retrieved, does these fields can reduce the amount of timeout ?

I receive sometimes some 429 or 500 result code from the google api, which is nice and normal (according to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)) but these timeouts are not at all what I expected.

Comment: Since Google API and Google Cloud SQL are two different services from two different servers, I'd imagine one could timeout but not the other.

Comment: I agree with you, but it was just an information that I have a normal network connection, which removes the hypothesis that my server was disconnected from the internet.

Comment: The server could possibly time out for various reasons even if not disconnected. This depends on how long the timeout is set for the connect.